# Deploy ECS ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService stuck [Possibly when loading Secrets]

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

When inejcting secrets to the Secrets object of the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`'s `taskImageOptions` imported from
`sm.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn` (including 6 digit hypen), the deploy gets stuck and does not work.

I have also tried importing the secrets by:

`sm.Secret.fromSecretNameV2` and the behaviour is the same.

#### Expected Behavior

ECS to deploy with custom secrets

#### Current Behavior

CDK deploy freezed stuck at ECS apiService deploy

#### Reproduction Steps

```
const importedSecrets = SECRET_NAMES.reduce((acc, key) => {
    const secret = sm.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(
      scope,
      `${config.ENVIRONMENT}/${key}`,
      secretFullArns[key], // full ARN of the secret identical as AWS
    );
    return {...acc, [key]: secret};
  }, {} as {[key: string]: sm.ISecret});
```

Where `SECRET_NAMES` is an array of secret names
Then,

```
  const secretsJson = SECRET_NAMES.reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(importedSecrets[key]),
    }),
    {},
  );
```

and then in the fargate service creator:

```
// Fargate service
this.backendService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
  scope,
  'apiService',
  {
    serviceName: 'apiService',
    cluster: this.ecsCluster,
    taskSubnets: {
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_NAT,
    },
    memoryLimitMiB: 2048,
    cpu: 1024,
    desiredCount: 1,
    taskImageOptions: {
      containerName: 'apiContainer',
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('../api-backend/', {
        followSymlinks: SymlinkFollowMode.ALWAYS,
      }),
      containerPort: config.PORT,
      environment: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: config.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
      },
      logDriver: ecs.LogDrivers.awsLogs({
        streamPrefix: `${config.PROJECT_NAME}-logStream`,
        logGroup: fargateLog,
      }),
      secrets: {
        DB_BUSINESS_PASSWORD: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(
          dbBusinessPasswordSecret,
          'password',
        ),
        DB_BUSINESS_HOST: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(
          dbBusinessPasswordSecret,
          'host',
        ),


        ...secretsJson. 
        // ===========>>> If i comment this line here, the deploy is successfull, but without the secrets i want.
        


      },
    },
  },
);
```

In the CDK template i see the correct secret name BUT WITHOUT THE HYPHEN

CDK TEMPLATE Secrets from ECS:

```
....
{
  "Name": "X_API_KEY",
  "ValueFrom": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      "",
      [
        "arn:",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
        },
        "secret-arn-as-it-is-in-aws-console/co****/staging/X_API_KEY"
// The secret arn is exactly equal as it is in aws but without the 6 char hyphen auto-generated when the secret was uploaded.
      ]
    ]
  }
},
...
```

Parameter name is: `/co****/staging/X_API_KEY`
But in the aws console the arn of the secret is exactly the same as the one in the cdk template but without the hyphen.
Im pretty sure that's the cause of the deploy stuck freeze.

Also,
IAM Permissions from the image task are fine, for example for the secret who's name is:
`/co***/staging/CIPHER_SECRET-??????` where the ? represent the auto hyphen 6 digit

[image: Console Synth CDK template]

#### Update:

I've tried to use `fromSecretAttributes` as suggested per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_secrets_manager_value.html

and the code is:

```
const importedSecrets = SECRET_NAMES.reduce((acc, key) => {
  const secret = sm.Secret.fromSecretAttributes(
    scope,
    `/cobuy/${config.ENVIRONMENT}/${key}`,
    {secretCompleteArn: secretFullArns[key]}, // full ARN with 6 digit hyphen
  );
  return {...acc, [key]: secret};
}, {} as {[key: string]: sm.ISecret});

const secretsJson = SECRET_NAMES.reduce(
  (acc, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(importedSecrets[key]),
  }),
  {} as {[key: string]: ecs.Secret},
);
```

Still not working but now the CDK Synthesis throws an error:

*must use only one of `secretCompleteArn` or `secretPartialArn`*

##### Interest data:

"aws-cdk-lib": "^2.27.0"

node -v => 14.19

Typescript "^4.7.2"

#### Other information

CDK JSON

```
{
  "app": "npx ts-node --prefer-ts-exts bin/CdkStarter.ts",
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway:usagePlanKeyOrderInsensitiveId": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-rds:lowercaseDbIdentifier": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-efs:defaultEncryptionAtRest": true,
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront:defaultSecurityPolicyTLSv1.2_2021": false,
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are the imported "secrets" stored in AWS?  `SECURE_STRING_SSM_PARAMETERS` suggests the Parameter Store, but the code treats them as Secret Manager secrets.

Comment: Thks for the answe @fedonev, 
The imported secrets are stored as Secrets in the AWS console, the array suggests parameter store but that's just because i have tried also with param store. But trust me, secrets are there in the AWS console and in the same region. That's from where i took the full ARN of each secret.

Comment: Got it.  You write _"In the CDK template i see the correct secret name..."_, but the OP template snippet has a SSM Parameter ARN, not a Secret ARN.  Please update the OP.  Also, OP also says _"Parameter name is..."_.  But you are not using parameters, right?

Comment: I just updated it, thanks @fedonev, sorry

Comment: Let's confirm IAM permissions.  In the synthed template, look for the Task Execution role policy (`AWS::IAM::Policy`).  What secret ARN resources are granted the `GetSecretValue` and `DescribeSecretValue` action?  We're looking for a secret ARN ending with `-??????` (literally a dash and 6 question marks, which in IAM-speak means all secret versions).

Comment: Permissions look fine, i've edited the post and attached proofs that the task execution role has the correct permissions. @fedonev, thanks for help btw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245647/discussion-between-fedonev-and-jp98).

Comment: @Jp98 were you able to resolve this? I am having the exact same issue right now-my fargate task does not start up, because I am getting:  no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action status code: 400